# Daily access pattern of a real cloud storage

Tags: data

for a current research project I would need file access traces of real world cloud storages. Unfortunately I was not able to find any yet.

More precisely I need real world traces with at least the following information: filename, file size, access time, operation (put, post, get, delete). The kind of data (if the files are images, textdata or something else) does not matter. Furthermore, it is also ok if it is not a cloud storage, but for example an online image gallery, as long as all 4 operations (put, post, get, delete) are included its fine for me.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try these links from [UCI Machine Learning Repository](http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets.html):

- [Anonymous Microsoft Web Data](http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Anonymous+Microsoft+Web+Data)
- [MSNBC.com Anonymous Web Data](http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/MSNBC.com+Anonymous+Web+Data)